# How can I display vpython graphics on external pop out canvas from inside Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, graphics, jupyter-notebook

How to display vpython graphics on external pop out canvas from inside Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Is the pop-out ability essential? Based on https://groups.google.com/g/vpython-users/c/q0g-MuQj4Sw/m/YL3HmYQYBgAJ , click [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jcoady/vpbindernbs/HEAD) to launch a session (with a configuration specified by [this repo](https://github.com/jcoady/vpbindernbs)). Then from the file navigation pane on the left side of the screen select one of the notebooks and try running the vpython code. If you prefer the classic notebook interface, use [this link to launch into the classic notebook interface](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jcoady/vpbindernbs/HEAD?urlpath=/tree/).

Comment: As for having it work via a pop-out. The closest I got was using JupyterLab, which the first link in my comment above launches, & using from the menubar 'View' > 'Render Side-by-Side'. There is a [Sidecar extension](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar) for JupyterLab that can give that effect. I wasn't able to find the right syntax in my quick tests to get it working for VPython. (Doesn't mean it doesn't; you may have to ask at the VPython google group.) JupyterLab has an ability for you to right-click & select 'Create New View for Output' but it fails for VPython output.